# sql: how to select the latest date if status doesn't equal to zero

Tags: sql

How can I get the latest date if the status doesn't equal to zero.

We have 3 columns - client, status and date.

```
client    status    datetime
------------------------------
Anton       2       2018-09-24
Anton       1       2018-08-12
Anton       0       2019-04-24
Anton       0       2019-04-25
Sergey      0       2019-09-24
Sergey      0       2019-08-12
Sergey      0       2019-04-24
Sergey      0       2019-04-25
```

If status > 0, we should take the latest date from those rows, which have status > 0 (no matter if it is 1 or 2 or any other number)

If all rows have status = 0, we should take the latest date among all rows.

Desired output:

```
Anton      2    2018-09-24
Sergey     0    2019-09-24
```

It is important, that the row "Anton      2 2018-09-24" was selected not because it contains '2' (max number of status), but because it contains the latest date among all the rows with datetime values > 0.

The rows shouldn't contain duplicates (i.e. 1 row = 1 client).

Comment: Can you provide some example data for where the status is null?

Comment: openshac - thank you for the question. I've made a mistake. There is no nulls in the dataset. There are only zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want in the results only the columns `client` and `datetime` you can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select client,
  coalesce(
    max(case when status > 0 then datetime end),
    max(case when status = 0 then datetime end)
  ) datetime
from tablename
where status is not null
group by client
```

Results:

```
> client | datetime           
> :----- | :---------
> Anton  | 2018-09-24 
> Sergey | 2019-09-24
```

If you also want the column `status` then join the above query to the table:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select client,
    coalesce(
      max(case when status > 0 then datetime end),
      max(case when status = 0 then datetime end)
    ) datetime
  from tablename
  where status is not null
  group by client
) tt on tt.client = t.client and tt.datetime = t.datetime
```

And another option with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.client, t.status, t.datetime
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (
      partition by client 
      order by case status when 0 then 1 else 0 end, datetime desc
    ) rn
  from tablename  
  where status is not null
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Results:

```
> client | status | datetime           
> :----- | -----: | :---------
> Anton  |      2 | 2018-09-24
> Sergey |      0 | 2019-09-24
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4dc8a66a8b8a6afc0756361337b23a3).

Comment: forpas, thank you so much. The second variant of your code is exactily what I needed.

Comment: @AlexIvanov check another option in my edited code if your database supports window functions.

Comment: I tried the code on the real data and found that rows with one client with differents status values (eg 1,2,0), but with the samestatus_datetime (e.g. 2019-09-16) are duplicated. But 1 row for 1 client is needed. Would you help me, please, to develop the code. Thank you.

Comment: Try my 3d query as it is now. This does not return duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
    client, 
    max(datetime) 
from 
    table
where 
    status is not null
group by 
    client
```

Comment: I don' think you can have a where clause after a group by.

Comment: @openshac, You can always have a group by clause after where clause.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai yes but the edit https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59497335/1 had the where clause after the group by clause. It's now been edited/corrected.

Comment: @openshac Ohhhh, Ok. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select client, max(status), max(date) from your_table
where status is not null
group by client
```

Comment: Jokkeri, thank you. Sorry, I've made a mistake. There are no nulls but zeros in the dataset. It's important to check - do all the rows have zeros in the status (if yes, then we select max(datetime), then no, we select max(datetime) from those which have status values >0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select max(datetime), client from users 
where status > 0
group by client;
```

Comment: Sachin, thank you. Sorry, I've made a mistake. There are no nulls but zeros in the dataset. It's important to check - do all the rows have zeros in the status (if yes, then we select max(datetime), then no, we select max(datetime) from those which have status values >0.

Comment: @AlexIvanov It's okay and I have update the query. I didn't get clear idea in your last stuff. I hope my query may help you

Comment: Sachin Shah, thank you. Your query doesn't take into account the case that all clients may have zeros in the status. See the 3d query of forpas.

Answer (score 0):

You can first pull the max record for status <> 0 then union all that with record status = 0. You may try below query -

```
SELECT T1.client, T1.status, T1.datetime
FROM YOUR_TAB T1
JOIN (SELECT status, datetime
      FROM YOUR_TAB
      WHERE status <> 0
      AND datetime = (SELECT MAX(datetime)
                      FROM YOUR_TAB
                      WHERE status <> 0)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 0, MAX(datetime)
      FROM YOUR_TAB
      WHERE status = 0) T2 ON T1.datetime = T2.datetime
                           AND T1.status = T2.status
```

Comment: Ankit Bajpai, thank you very much for your code.
I tried your code on the real data (see below) and received this: 
client 2, 0, 2019-04-16
client 2, 1, 2018-06-07
Expected:  client1 0 2019-04-04, client2 1 2018-06-07
payinn sfm_now status_datetime
client1 0 2019-03-01
client1 0 2018-09-11
client1 0 2019-04-04
client1 0 2018-07-05
client2 0 2019-04-15
client2 0 2019-04-16
client2 1 2018-06-07
client2 0 2018-09-05. I've corrected the body of the topic.